# Getting the remote server returned an error 403 forbidden exception

Tags: wcf, http-status-code-403

I am trying to access https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=service+language:assembly%26sort=stars%26order=desc from a WCF service and getting `the remote server returned an error (403) forbidden` exception.

I have already tried adding `httprequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;` and 
`httprequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";` but none of this has helped me so far.

Below is the code used:

```
HttpWebRequest httprequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=service+language:assembly%26sort=stars%26order=desc");
httprequest.Proxy = new WebProxy()
{
   Address = new Uri(Proxy_address),
   Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials
};
httprequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
httprequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";
httprequest.KeepAlive = true;
HttpWebResponse GISTResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httprequest.GetResponse();
```

Please help.

Comment: what is Proxy_address here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be a lot of things.
Testing your code, I could notice you're missing **UserAgent** and your **Accept** is wrong, due to requirements of **git**.

Try to remove the Accept and add this line:

```
httprequest.UserAgent = "My request";
```

If you still have problems, you can inspect by yourself what's happening adding a try and this catch block, and inspect the reponseText from **git**:

```
catch (WebException exception)
            {
                string responseText;

                using (var reader = new StreamReader(exception.Response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I added UserAgent and it worked fine. Thanks :). But can you tell me why UserAgent is required? Is there any default value present for UserAgent or not?

Comment: UserAgent is optional ( http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#user-agent), but it is required by Git, it must theirs polices.